# ANTLR 4 is too greedy: mismatched input

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have this simple grammar:

```
shape_grammar
:
    decoration*
    start_entry
    decoration*
    //shape_rule+
;

decoration
    :
        include_statement
        | attr
        | resource
    ;

include_statement
    :
        'include' '"' PATH '"' END
    ;

attr
    :
        'attr' ATTR_TYPE IDENTIFIER ('(' INT ',' INT ')')? END
    ;

resource
    :
        RESOURCE_TYPE IDENTIFIER '"' PATH '"' END
    ;

start_entry
    :
        'start' '"' IDENTIFIER '"' END
    ;

... more rules ...

PATH
    :
        ~('"'|'\n'|'\r')+
    ;
ATTR_TYPE
    :
        'int'
        |'float'
        |'bool'
    ;
RESOURCE_TYPE
    :
        'model'
    ;


IDENTIFIER
    :
        [a-z]+
        | ([a-z][a-z_0-9]+)
    ;
```

For the input:

```
include "GrammaticBasic";
attr float xxx (0, 1);
attr int yyy (2, 6);
attr float zzz (0, 1);
attr float www (0, 1);
```

I always get the error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'include "GrammatikBasic";' expecting {'include', 'attr', 'start', 'model'}
```

Why does ANTLR try to match the whole line onto the first part of the rules?
It seems too greedy to me.

What I'm doing wrong?

(This text is to bypass STACKOVERFLOWS "Your question is mostly code try to add some details" error. )

Comment: Not even close to being an 'exact' duplicate.

Comment: The start rule requires a `start_entry` as part of any valid input.  There is none to match. So, ANTLR sees everything as mismatched input.